# SQL Joining Multiple Tables mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey Guys I need Help with an SQL statement. There are 5 tables total and I need to join multiple tables for a SELECT statement.
These are the tables:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| person_id | first_name | last_name  |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|         1 | Tom        | Hanks      |
|         2 | Anne       | Hathaway   |
|         3 | Tom        | Cruise     |
|         4 | Meryl      | Streep     |
|         5 | Chris      | Pratt      |
|         6 | Halle      | Berry      |
|         7 | Robert     | De Niro    |
|         8 | Julia      | Roberts    |
|         9 | Denzel     | Washington |
|        10 | Melissa    | McCarthy   |
+-----------+------------+------------+

+-------------+----------------------+
| building_id | building_name        |
+-------------+----------------------+
|           1 | Headquarters         |
|           2 | Main Street Building |
+-------------+----------------------+

+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| room_id | room_number | building_id | capacity |
+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|       1 | 100         |           1 |        5 |
|       2 | 200         |           1 |        4 |
|       3 | 300         |           1 |       10 |
|       4 | 10          |           2 |        4 |
|       5 | 20          |           2 |        4 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+

+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| meeting_id | room_id | meeting_start       | meeting_end         |
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          1 |       1 | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 |
|          2 |       1 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 | 2016-12-25 12:00:00 |
|          3 |       1 | 2016-12-25 11:00:00 | 2016-12-25 12:00:00 |
|          4 |       2 | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 |
|          5 |       4 | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 |
|          6 |       5 | 2016-12-25 14:00:00 | 2016-12-25 16:00:00 |
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+

+-----------+------------+
| person_id | meeting_id |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 |          1 |
|        10 |          1 |
|         1 |          2 |
|         2 |          2 |
|         3 |          2 |
|         4 |          2 |
|         5 |          2 |
|         6 |          2 |
|         7 |          2 |
|         8 |          2 |
|         9 |          3 |
|        10 |          3 |
|         1 |          4 |
|         2 |          4 |
|         8 |          5 |
|         9 |          5 |
|         1 |          6 |
|         2 |          6 |
|         3 |          6 |
+-----------+------------+
```

The problem:
Construct the SQL statement to find all the meetings that Tom Hanks has to attend. Display the following columns:
Person’s first name
Person’s last name
Building name
Room number
Meeting start date and time
Meeting end date and time

My statement:

```
SELECT person.first_name, person.last_name, building.building_name,
    ->
    -> room.room_number, meeting.meeting_start, meeting.meeting_end
    ->
    -> FROM person
    ->
    -> JOIN building
    ->
    -> ON person.person_id = building.building_id
    ->
    -> JOIN room
    ->
    -> ON  person.person_id = room.room_id
    ->
    -> JOIN meeting
    ->
    -> ON person.person_id = meeting.meeting_id
    ->
    -> WHERE person_id = 1;
```

RESULT:

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| first_name | last_name | building_name | room_number | meeting_start       | meeting_end         |
+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Tom        | Hanks     | Headquarters  | 100         | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Tom Hanks has multiple meetings.(4 to be exact) How do I show the 4 meetings? Not sure what to do here. It is only showing 1 with my statement.

Comment: Hint: Something like `ON person.person_id = building.building_id` should ring an alarm. Or does an ID of a person really identify a building? And you completely neglected the last table (for which you haven't revealed the name)., But it is a very important table for this task!

Answer (score -1):

This query should give you what you want (barring any spelling mistakes :P!)

`SELECT person.first_name, 
        person.last_name, 
        building.building_name, 
        room.room_number, 
        meeting.meeting_start, 
        meeting.meeting_end
FROM    person
INNER JOIN person_meeting ON person_meeting.person_id = person.person_id
INNER JOIN meeting ON meeting.meeting_id = person_meeting.meeting_id
INNER JOIN room ON room.room_id = meeting.room_id
INNER JOIN building on building.building_id = room.building_id
WHERE person.person_id = 1`

With this query you are joining the tables on the relationships you've created.
A person is linked to meeting via `meeting.person_id = person.person_id` a meeting is linked to a room via `room.room_id = meeting.room_id` and a room is linked to a building via `building.building_id = room.room_id` then finally filtering down these to only show where `person.person_id = 1`

The issue with your query was you tried to join everything onto person via person_id

`JOIN building ON person.person_id = building.building_id
+-------------+----------------------+
| building_id | building_name        |
+-------------+----------------------+
|           1 | Headquarters         |<-
|           2 | Main Street Building |
+-------------+----------------------+`

from this table we will only get building_id = 1

`JOIN room ON  person.person_id = room.room_id
+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| room_id | room_number | building_id | capacity |
+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|       1 | 100         |           1 |        5 | <- 
|       2 | 200         |           1 |        4 |
|       3 | 300         |           1 |       10 |
|       4 | 10          |           2 |        4 |
|       5 | 20          |           2 |        4 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+`

from this table we will only get `room_id = 1`

`JOIN meeting ON person.person_id = meeting.meeting_id
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| meeting_id | room_id | meeting_start       | meeting_end         |
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          1 |       1 | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 | <-
|          2 |       1 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 | 2016-12-25 12:00:00 |
|          3 |       1 | 2016-12-25 11:00:00 | 2016-12-25 12:00:00 |
|          4 |       2 | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 |
|          5 |       4 | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 |
|          6 |       5 | 2016-12-25 14:00:00 | 2016-12-25 16:00:00 |
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+`

from this table we can see we will only get `meeting_id = 1`

Primary Keys/Foreign Keys

- Person.person_id is your PK and meeting.person_id is your FK
- room.room_id is your PK and meeting.room_id is your FK
- Building.building_id is your PK and room.building_id is your FK

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54d6e/2)

Comment: Does not work. ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'meeting.person_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: You be not given me table names so I had to guess. Modify question to name your tables. However there should be sufficient information to solve this yourself :)

Comment: person, building, room, meeting, person_meeting. those are the table names in order.

Comment: Try now. On phone so might have made a spelling mistake.

Comment: It shows 3 meetings only. Should be 4. Jesus this is a pain

Comment: Based on the data you have provided it will definitely work. I'll do an sqlfiddle tomorrow to prove it. Double check your data

Answer (score -1):

Was able to find a solution. JOIN was not needed...

```
SELECT first_name,last_name ,building_name,room_number ,meeting_start,meeting_end
FROM person P, building B,person_meeting PM,meeting M,room R
WHERE
P.person_id=PM.person_id
AND M.room_id=R.room_id
AND B.building_id=R.building_id
AND PM.meeting_id=M.meeting_id
AND P.first_name='Tom'
AND P.last_name='Hanks';
```

Comment: This is still implicitly joining, and it also is pretty bad practice.  Use `inner join` and if needed, `left join`...building out queries this way hasn't been considered best practice for a LONG time.

Comment: How can I convert this to inner join?

Comment: exactly as @Matt did with his answer above.